# How do I overlay container div on another container using Bootstrap or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: this is a layout that i want to achieve.]

---

I have designed a layout using Bootstrap 4 in which container b is next to container A. but I want container B to overlay some part of container A as shown in image.
How can I achieve this type of layout? Any help or reference would be appreciated.

```html
  <!-- container A -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h4>HOW IT WORKS</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-2 px-0">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      card 1 title
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                       card 1 body
              
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2">
              <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      card 2 header
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        card 2 body
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                      card 3 header
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      card 4 body
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- container B -->

        <div class="container rounded-border">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
              <h4 class="display-4">What is Lorem Ipsum</h4>
              <p>
              ustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker includin
              </p>
            </div>
           
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Won't bootstrap modals do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a straight-CSS solution using just an `absolute`-positioned element inside `relative`-positioned element. The `top` and `left` style properties determine where Container B appears with respect to its parent div.

```css
#outerContainer{
  position: relative;
}
#containerA{ 
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px gray; 
}
#containerB{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
#rest-of-page{
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div id="containerA">Container A</div>
  <div id="containerB">Container B</div>
  <div id="rest-of-page">(Rest of Page)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. but i have encountered another problem when i positioned container B as absolute  .content after that also get overlay-ed like "Rest of page" in above answer. but i want to position "Res of page" after container B.

Comment: If you give "rest-of-page" `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, then it can be shifted below "Container B" with the `top` property. (See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_top.asp for details.)

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute positioning on container B and find the desired position and then use z-index on the same container and set it to 1. This will 'overlay' element B on top of element A.

z-index:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp